# android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using Facebook SDK for login use and getting a crash stating

android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class which is part of

SourceApplicationInfo.java line 127
com.facebook.appevents.internal.SourceApplicationInfo$Factory.create

Does anyone one have an idea why is this happening or this is a library issue?

Comment: Same here with FB SDK 4.32.0. Did you find a solution?